# Unicode fonts in pdf at GAE with web2py/pyfpdf

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf, web2py

I'm writing an app, which results with pdf file with some text with unicode characters. On GAE devserver it works good, but after deploy it can't import font file (crash after add_font() (pyfpdf)).

The code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def fun1(): 

from gluon.contrib.pyfpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin
class MyFPDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass

pdf =MyFPDF()
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('DejaVu','',16)
pdf.write(10,'test-ąśł')

response.headers['Content-Type']='application/pdf'
return pdf.output(dest='S')
```

The font files (with a file DejaVuSansCondensed.pkl generated after first run on web2py server...) is in /gluon/contrib/fpdf/font. I didn't add anything to routers.py (I'm using Pattern-based system) also app.yaml is not changed. And I get this:

```
In FILE: /base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/web2py-04.369240954601780983/applications/app3/controllers/default.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/web2py-04.369240954601780983/gluon/restricted.py", line 212, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/web2py-04.369240954601780983/applications/app3/controllers/default.py", line 674, in <module>
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/web2py-04.369240954601780983/gluon/globals.py", line 194, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/web2py-04.369240954601780983/applications/app3/controllers/default.py", line 493, in fun1
    pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/web2py-04.369240954601780983/gluon/contrib/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 432, in add_font
    font_dict = pickle.load(fh)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27p/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 966, in load_string
    raise ValueError, "insecure string pickle"
ValueError: insecure string pickle
```

As I said on local (both web2py/rocket and gae) it works well. After deploy only something like this works:

```
pdf =MyFPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial','',16)
pdf.write(10,'testąśł')
```

But without "unusual" characters...

The best solution would be to add my font files (like DejaVu), but basically I need unicode characters in any font... maybe some "half-solution" to use "generic GAE unicode" fonts... if it exist something like this...

Comment: I would look at resolving the insecure pickle error.  This is often caused by mismatched open 'rb' vs 'w'  one open in ascii mode the other in binary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion Tim!

I found [some solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/xcsFLSZ2X8g/dUkR8ISsDgEJ)... it isn't the best one, but it works...

The problem is with using pickle on GAE. The best solution (probably) would be to overload/rewrite the `add_font()` function where for GAE, in such a way, that it would write to a datastore instead of a filesystem. Additionaly `ValueError: insecure string pickle` error can still occur, I tried b64 encoding according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963602/gae-valueerror-insecure-string-pickle?rq=1). But still I get errors. So my solution is to overload `add_font()` function with commented out/deleted parts:

```
if os.path.exists(unifilename):
    fh = open(unifilename)
    try:
        font_dict = pickle.load(fh)
    finally:
    fh.close()
else:
```

and

```
try:
    fh = open(unifilename, "w")
    pickle.dump(font_dict, fh)
    fh.close()
except IOError, e:
    if not e.errno == errno.EACCES:
        raise  # Not a permission error.
```

Because of this the function every time calculates little bit more instead of just reading data from the pickle... but it works on GAE.